# Use a variable to determine let bindings

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

Is there a way to use a variable to hold the set of let bindings for passing to a later call?

For example

```
(setq a '((org-export-with-toc nil)
          (blah 2)))
```

Then

```
(let-wrapper a
  ;; Perform the export here)
```

This is for the goal of allowing [outorg-export](https://github.com/jleechpe/outorg-export) to add an `options` alist specifying how to export the indicated element.

Editing to provide clarity (`@sds`'s answer of using `cl-progv` is what I needed):

I want to be able to pass a variable/alist of values as part of an 'export definition' to the org-export engine.

> ```
> If NIL, nothing will be exported.  Otherwise it must be a list of
> entries for sections to be exported and exporter to use.  Each entry
> is a list like this:
>
>     (headline &optional exporter file level options)
>
> headline     Outshine commented headline to export from.  If t,
>              defaults to entire file.
> exporter     Org exporter format to use when exporting.  If not
>              specified (blank, t or nil), defaults to an Org
>              file.  This is a symbol for the exporter to use.  If
>              exporting to PDF, specify `PDF' rather than `LATEX'
>              otherwise it will be exported as a `.tex' file.
> file         If set, specifies the export file name.  If `T', defaults
>              to the name of the exported buffer.  If `NIL', defaults
>              to the name of the headline being exported if specified,
>              or buffer file name if entire buffer is exported.
> level        By default `SECTION' will search for top level headlines
>              `* '.  Level allows for exporting specific sublevels
>              instead.  This integer indicates how many stars to match.
> options      List of export variables to be set prior to export.
>              These values are provided as a let binding around the
>              export process.
> ```

An example command would be `("Documentation" ascii t 1 ((org-export-with-toc nil)))`

In the export command itself each value is let bound to the appropriate field, and then in the end `org-ascii-export-to-ascii` performs the export (replace ascii as specified).  I'd tried using `:EXPORT_OPTIONS:` properties but they were not being recognized when converting to outorg and exporting, and `#+OPTIONS:` were not either.  Instead (also allowing different options based on export format, or even multiple exports to the same format with different options) I want to use the `options` value as a set of let-bindings around the export process to allow it to be modified.

Comment: Seems like you want a `destructuring-bind`

Comment: Or perhaps `let-alist`.

Comment: I tried `let-alist`, however I don't need to access the values, only have them bound. It was not binding the values, only making them accessible

Comment: Maybe you could write a pseudo-code example of how you are going to use it? It sounds like there might be an easier solution to this problem (eg. passing a function, a special data-structure, using a macro that does something conditionally etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and what you want is run-time evaluation
of the variables to be bound, then you need
[`progv`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progv.htm)
implemented in Emacs as
[`cl-progv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Dynamic-Bindings.html):

```
(progv (mapcar #first a) (mapcar #'second a)
  ....)
```