# Dynamic generation of varlist in a let form

Tags: elisp-macros, let-binding

Let's say I have a `let` form and I want to generate the `varlist`
dynamically from another function. Something like this:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2)
      (the-dyn-gen))
  body...
  )
```

I have some local vars already in the `varlist` namely x and y. But I want to call a function that I called `the-dyn-gen` which returns a list like this `'((a 3) (b 4))` now I need to make these sub lists `(a 3)` & `(b 3)`  part of the `varlist`.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html#Macros) could do that:

```el
(defmacro mylet (defs fun body)
  (list 'let (append defs (funcall fun)) body))

;; example uses
(defun the-dyn-gen () 
  '((a 3) (b 3)))

(mylet ((x 1) (y 2)) the-dyn-gen (+ a b x y))

(mylet ((x 1)) the-dyn-gen (+ a b x))

(mylet nil the-dyn-gen (+ a b))
```

Disclaimer: while this seems to work, macros can be [tricky](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Problems-with-Macros.html#Problems-with-Macros).

Note that `macroexpand` is a nice function to test a macro. Here

```
(macroexpand '(mylet ((x 1) (y 2)) the-dyn-gen (+ a b x y)))
```

results in

```
(let ((x 1) (y 2) (a 3) (b 3)) (+ a b x y))
```

Note: related [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/use-a-variable-to-determine-let-bindings?rq=1) with `progv`.